# Integration testing: verifty anything that gets passed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nunit, integration-testing, moq

For my Asp.Net Core application, I am writing integration tests using nUnit framework with Moq.

I have services (Mega Services) that are working with multiple other services (Tiny Services).
For instance I have a Mega Service called **WorkflowService** that calls two tiny services : **StepService** and **HistoryService**.

I am writing an integration test to make sure proper methods of **StepService** and **Historyservice** are always being called by **WorkflowService**.

The problem is that the data which **WorkflowService** passes to my tiny services needs calculation and typecasting. Those works are handled in separate Unit Tests (using Moq for simulation) and I do not want to repeat them again here. I just want to check if the tiny services' methods are called or not. Actually I do not care about the input data here.

As far as I know, when we use `Verify` method of a `Mock` object, we should pass the parameters as well.

Is there some workaround by which I can ask the `Verify` method just to check the method invocation and not the input data?

Somehow it should ignore the input, or just check the type (and not the object reference) so that I can pass any data to it without being concerned about the validity of the input.

Comment: Please, share your code and tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    mockSomeClass.Verify(mock => mock.DoSomething(It.IsAny<object>()), Times.Once());
```